# Use an array in an array

Tags: php, arrays

All,
I've got the following code:

```
array(
        'id'        => 'tweet_slider',
        'name'      => __( 'Slide', TB_GETTEXT_DOMAIN ),
        'desc'      => __( 'Select the icon you\'d like shown before the Tweet.', TB_GETTEXT_DOMAIN ),
        'type'      => 'select',
        'std'       => 'twitter_display_option',
        'options'   => array(
            'single_twitter'    => __( 'Show Single Tweet', TB_GETTEXT_DOMAIN ),
            'slider_twitter'    => __( 'Show Twitter Slider', TB_GETTEXT_DOMAIN ),
        )
    ),
```

This works fine but I'd basically like to add options to my options array dynamically. I tried to do something like this:

```
$menus = wp_get_nav_menus();
foreach ( $menus as $menu ) :
    $menu_options =  'single_twitter'   => __( 'Show Single Tweet', TB_GETTEXT_DOMAIN ),
endforeach;
$menu_options = (array)$menu_options;

array(
        'id'        => 'menu_options',
        'name'      => __( 'Enter in your Menu Options', TB_GETTEXT_DOMAIN ),
        'desc'      => __( 'Enter in your menu options.', TB_GETTEXT_DOMAIN ),
        'std'       => '',
        'type'      => 'select',
        'options'   =>  $menu_options,
    ),
```

This gives me the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW

Is there a way to go about doing something like this?? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$menu_options = array();
foreach ( $menus as $menu ) :
    $menu_options[] = array( 'single_twitter' => __( 'Show Single Tweet', TB_GETTEXT_DOMAIN));
endforeach;
```

**Edit:** Per the comment, you could try something like:

```
foreach ( $menus as $menu ) :
    $menu_options[] = array( $menu->menu_id => __( $menu->name, TB_GETTEXT_DOMAIN));
endforeach;
```

Comment: If I want wanted to do something like: $menu->menu_id => __( $menu->name, TB_GETTEXT_DOMAIN) and make that in my array, how would that look?

Comment: I think we are almost there, however the output looks like this: Array ( [0] => Array ( [1] => Main Menu ) ) where I think the output should look like this: Array ([0] => Data [1] => Main Menu)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a syntax error because you cannot use the `=>` symbol in that position. You can add an item to an array using:

```
$menu_options['single_twitter'] = __( 'Show Single Tweet', TB_GETTEXT_DOMAIN );
```

or, in general:

```
$menu_options = array();
foreach ($menus as $menu) {
    $key = ...
    $value = ...
    $menu_options[$key] = $value;
}
```

where `$key` and `$value` are obtained using `$menu`. In the main array, you can then write:

```
'options' => $menu_options
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to build an array from scratch is

```
$myArray = array(); 
$myArray['some_key'] = some_value ; 
$myArray['some_other_key'] = some_other_value ;
```

Try and apply that to your situation in your foreach loop.